# Barcode Scanner doesn't return a response in production mode

Tags: react-native, expo

Device: iPhone 6s+ (v11.2.5)

My app is using Expo `https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner.html`

In Expo application (development). The barcode scanner is working perfectly. However, when we upload it in TestFlight and download the app. The barcode scanner is not working anymore even though I allowed it to use camera.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    {this.state.hasCameraPermission === null
      ? <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>
      : this.state.hasCameraPermission === false
          ? <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
              Camera permission is not granted
            </Text>
          : <BarCodeScanner
              onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead.bind(this)}
              style={{
                height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
              }}
            />}
  </View>

_handleBarCodeRead = result => {
 if (this.state.lastScannedUrl !== result.data) {
  this.setState({
    lastScannedUrl: result.data
  })

  if (this.props.inventories.inventory.length > 0) {
    let item = (this.props.inventories.inventory).find(element => {
      return element.id == result.data
    })

    if (item !== undefined) {
      Actions.viewItem({inventory: item, route: this.state.route})
    } else {
      Alert.alert(
        'Alert',
        'No item found',
        [
          {text: 'Back', onPress: () => Actions.pop(), style: 'cancel'},
          {text: 'Search Again', onPress: () => this.setState({lastScannedUrl: null})},
        ],
        { cancelable: true }
      )
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get any progress on this issue? I'm experiencing this right now

Comment: It may be noteworthy that `onBarCodeRead` was changed to `onBarCodeScanned` in a recent version. I am using the latter, but the method does not execute when the app is run in TestFlight. It works just fine when running inside the Expo Client app, even when I turn off dev mode via `expo start --no-dev --minify`.